# Setting Label Text in XAML to string constant

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, static-members

I have a single string constant that I have to re-use in several different XAML layouts, so instead of duplicating it, I'd like to just bind it to a constant.

I have a class which defines the string in C#:

```
public static class StringConstants
{
     public static string MyString { get { return "SomeConstant"; } }
}
```

I'd like to be able to set the value through XAML via something like the following:

```
<Label Content="{Binding local:StringConstants.MyString}"/>
```

Is this achievable? I've searched for examples, but I've only found samples that involve some tinkering in the code-behind and I'm wondering if there's a simpler, XAML-only solution if I know that I just need to set the value once based on a string value that will never change.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are binding to a static member so you should use [`x:Static` Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx):

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static local:StringConstants.MyString}}"/>
```

According to @H.B.'s comment it's not necessary to use Binding so it's simpler to use:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static local:StringConstants.MyString}"/>
```

Comment: @H.B. What do you recommend instead?

Comment: @nonsensical101: Just leaving it out: `Content="{x:Static local:StringConstants.MyString}"`

Comment: This doesn't work for UWP apps, unfortunately. Anyone have an idea how to do it for those?

Comment: @H.B. Some reasons you may use a binding - formatted strings. multibindings, value conversion

Answer (score 0):

Put the public static string MyString in your App.xaml.cs.   Then you can reference it as follows.

```
    Content="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=MyString}"
```

Answer (score -1):

In the case that you have a constant inside of a **non-static** class, this doesn't work.

My solution for binding to a constant inside of a **view model** (MVVM).
It uses a getter property with less code for wrapping.

```
// view model
public const string MyString = "abc";
public string MyStringConst => MyString;
```

.

```
<!-- WPF -->    
<Label Content="{Binding MyStringConst, FallbackValue='abc'}" />
```

The FallbackValue is used for the Designer preview.