# How to access a static variable from code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Question:** Is it possible to access a static variable from code behind to be used in XAML?

Reason: I want a single string variable to keep a menu name which will be used in different places (in code behind and also in XAML).

Example (code behind):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly string menuName = "MyMenu";

    ... other code ...
}
```

Example (XAML):

```
<MenuItem Header="... here I want my menuName to appear ..." />
```

Comment: have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794274/setting-label-text-in-xaml-to-string-constant

Answer (score 3):

for that you would need to instantiate your class in xaml once, then you can use the static member.

it would be better to create a separate class for static variables and load it in xaml in resources.

something like this

```
<Window.Resources>
        <!-- Create an instance of the  class called MyClass -->

        <my:MyClass x:Key="MyClass" />

</Window.Resources>
```

then use it as something like

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Static my:MyClass.MyProperty}" Width="500" Height="100" />
```

or

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyClass},Path=MyProperty}" />
```

also see
[XAML Binding to static classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959788/xaml-binding-to-static-classes)

[How to bind in XAML to a static property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622013/how-to-bind-in-xaml-to-a-static-property)

Comment: It would be even better if the resource was create app level.

Answer (score 1):

You should add it to project [Resource dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

go to you project -> Properties -> Resources-> Add Resource Button

then you can use it in Xaml or code behind like that:

-- XAML---

```
  <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.menuName}" />
```

--- Code behind ----

```
Properties.Resources.menuName
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  not do this  for the simple reason that when you  bind on your property  you  will get an infinite  nested calls to MainWindow  which will generate an  `'System.StackOverflowException'` you  should use a container class like this

```
    namespace WpfApplication2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.DataContext = this; 
            }


        }
        public  class  WindowMessagesManager
        {
            private static string _header;
            public static string Header1
            {
                get { return "My Header"; }
                set { _header = value; }
            }

        }

}
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <prop:WindowMessagesManager x:Key="window" ></prop:WindowMessagesManager>
        //you can  try to uncomment this and you will get an exception 
        <!--<prop:MainWindow x:Key="window"></prop:MainWindow>-->
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu>
        <MenuItem  Height="100" Width="100" Header="{Binding  Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=window}, Path=Header1}"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```