# Setting label content causes issues

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I'm trying to set a label's content to: *if* the value in my textbox is larger than 6000 it should display `"Under-Run Bumper"` and *if not* it should be `string.Empty` or `""`, but when I try to run my code, I get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

```
private void txtExternalLength_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtExternalLength.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txtExternalLength.Text) >= 6000)
            lblUnderRunBumper.Content = "Under-Run Bumper";
        else lblUnderRunBumper.Content = ""; //Error here
    }
}
```

Comment: @rashfmnb Thanks for the comment man. Why should I use `Length` at the end? Or what is the purpose of doing it like this?

Comment: i have delete it by considering my self wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794274/setting-label-text-in-xaml-to-string-constant

Comment: `lblUnderRunBumper` might be null. If you enter "6001" in `txtExternalLength`, do you get the error? How is `lblUnderRunBumper` defined? Can you show us the XAML where `lblUnderRunBumper` is defined? Does it have a template?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the numbers of chars in your textbox you should use .Length.
This will return an Integer with the number of Chars.

```
private void txtExternalLength_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtExternalLength.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            if (txtExternalLength.Length >= 6000)
            {
                lblUnderRunBumper.Content = "Under-Run Bumper";
            }
            else 
            {
                lblUnderRunBumper.Content = ""; //Error here
            }
        }
    }
```

But if you want to work with an Integer which is written in your Textbox u can try this:

```
    private void txtExternalLength_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (txtExternalLength.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                    int count = 0;

                    bool result = Int32.TryParse(txtExternalLength.Text, out count);
                    // Int32.TryParse(input, out output) will try to Convert the text (string) of your Textbox to an Int32. If it is successfull the result will be true, else it will be false.
                    if (result && count >= 6000)
                    {
                        lblUnderRunBumper.Content = "Under-Run Bumper";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        lblUnderRunBumper.Content = ""; //Error here
                    }
                }
            }
```